# Tensorflow expected 2 inputs but received 1 input tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, bert-language-model

Hey guys so I'm building a model based on the Roberta-Base and at the end when I try to fit the model I get a error saying: `ValueError: Layer model_39 expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(16, 128) dtype=float64>]`

I'm using `tf.data.Dataset` to make the dataset:

```
def map_dataset(ids, masks, labels):
    return {'input_ids': ids, 'input_mask': masks}, labels

# Create dataset
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((ids, mask, labels))
dataset.map(map_dataset)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(10000).batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
```

Supposedly dataset is generating 2 inputs properly but for some reason fit is refusing to work and I'm not sure why.

Full code:

```
LEN_SEQ = 128
BATCH_SIZE = 16
TEST_TRAIN_SPLIT = 0.9
TRANSFORMER = 'roberta-base'

# Load roberta model
base_model = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# Define input layers
input_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(LEN_SEQ,), name='input_ids', dtype='int32')
input_mask = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(LEN_SEQ,), name='input_mask', dtype='int32')

# Define hidden layers
embedding = base_model([input_ids, input_mask])[1]
layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(LEN_SEQ * 2, activation='relu')(embedding)
layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(LEN_SEQ, activation='relu')(layer)

# Define output
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax', name='output')(layer)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_ids, input_mask], outputs=[output])

model.compile(
    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=1e-3, decay=1e-4),
    loss = CategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics = [
        CategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')
    ]
)

# Load data
df = pd.read_csv('train-processed.csv')
df = df.head(100)
samples_count = len(df)

# Tokenize data
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(TRANSFORMER)
tokens = tokenizer(
    df['first_Phrase'].tolist(),
    max_length=LEN_SEQ,
    truncation=True,
    padding='max_length',
    add_special_tokens=True,
    return_tensors='tf'
)
ids = tokens['input_ids']
mask = tokens['attention_mask']

def map_dataset(ids, masks, labels):
    return {'input_ids': ids, 'input_mask': masks}, labels

# Create dataset
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((ids, mask, labels))
dataset.map(map_dataset)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(10000).batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)

# Split data intro train and test
train_size = int((samples_count / BATCH_SIZE) * TEST_TRAIN_SPLIT)
train = dataset.take(train_size)
test = dataset.skip(train_size)

# Train model
history = model.fit(
    train,
    validation_data=test,
    epochs=2
)
```

Inside dataset -> `<BatchDataset shapes: ((16, 128), (16, 128), (16, 5)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64)>`

Inside train -> `<TakeDataset shapes: ((16, 128), (16, 128), (16, 5)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64)>`

Data example:

[image]

Any help appreciated. I'm new to transformers so please feel free to point any extra considerations.

Comment: You have your dataset structured incorrectly for `.fit()` if you're trying to use 3D tensors. If you pass a 3D tensor as input, the tuple should be (features, label, sample_weight). That's not the current issue though. The current issue is you're passing a single dataset to `.fit()` when the model is multi-input. Multi-inputs with `.fit()` need to be in the form of a list, not a `tf.data.Dataset`, or similar.

Comment: @Djinn I really appreciate the comment but would you mind writing a answer with possible fixes? I understand what your saying but I'm not sure how to apply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix this as far as I know with the help of @Djinn.
I did remove dataset API and instead built my own datasets manually using the following code:

```
# Split into training and validation sets
train_size = int(samples_count * TEST_TRAIN_SPLIT)
train = [ids[:train_size], mask[:train_size]]
train_labels = labels[:train_size]
test = [ids[train_size:], mask[train_size:]], labels[train_size:]
# Train model
history = model.fit(
    train, train_labels,
    validation_data=test,
    epochs=10
)
```

This seems to be working and `fit()` accepted this data, but feel free to point out if this is wrong or could be made differently.